# Why is the line between two points called the line of the "secant"?

Tags: trigonometry

The definition of the slope of the line of the secant is:

slope = $\frac{y2-y1}{x2-x1}$

The definition of the slope of the tangent line is:

$\lim_{h->0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

I understand why they call it the tangent line since the angle to the x axis will be $tan(\theta) =\frac{Opp}{Adj}$ equivalent to opposite of adjacent.

Secant is the inverse trig function of cosine, so $\sec(\theta)=\frac{Hyp}{Adj}$

But I don't understand how secant is related to the slope of its line? I looked it up and I found out that the word secant comes from the Latin word *secare*, which means to cut. But is there any relation to secant and it's angle?

Comment: I don't think tangent line is called that because of $\tan\theta = opp/adj$, I think they both derive their meaning separately from whatever common root word tangent comes from.

Comment: Perhaps. This was also a thought I had, but I'd like to think there is another reasons since, tangent and secant both have specific definitions associated with them. I thought it would be unlikely that mathematics gave them specific definitions in one circumstance and then a more flexible definition in another. But then again, what do I know.

Comment: The trigonometric functions $\tan$ and $\sec$ have no real relation to tangent lines or secant lines.

Comment: @Lenny That is false. [See the picture here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unitcircledefs.svg).

Comment: /facepalm/ Didn't read the last paragraph. My apologies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you can define $sec(\theta)$ as a length on the unit circle.  $sec$ corresponds to the  length of the line from $(0,0)$ to $(1, \tan(\theta))$ and $tan$ corresponds to the length of the segment from $(1,0)$ to $(1, \tan(\theta))$.  See the figure [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unitcircledefs.svg).  Clearly the $sec$ segment cuts the circle and $tan$ is tangent to it.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. Thank you, very insightful.

Comment: Link is broken; is this the figure you meant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unitcircledefs.svg